# How to recover Chrome after tight loop?

Tags: google-chrome, while-loop

I am running Node.js on localhost:3001 and unintentionally wrote some code with an infinite while loop. This locked up Chrome to the point where the only resolution was to kill the browser. Since then, I found the problem in my code using Firefox, and fixed the code, but even after restarting Chrome, it will not load my page. I even changed the port that the server runs on, and the cache is disabled with developer tools open - Chrome simply refuses to load the page. I see a single request to the server for the page, but in Chrome it just registers as Pending.

Has Chrome maybe flagged this page as suspect, somehow? How do I get it to play again? I would at least expect Chrome to offer some opportunity to kill a tight loop - like Firefox does - but I've yet to see it. Is there some setting I can tweak? I'm on version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit), although now that I opened the About page, I see that it is updating Chrome, so maybe that will fix it.

UPDATE: It didn't fix it, but it works in Incognito mode. ???!!!
UPDATE: Disabling all of my extensions also didn't fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I found a setting in Chrome: "Continue to run background apps when Chrome is closed"

I turned that off, and now it works again.